# bash script which executes a python script which prompts user

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script which sometimes prompts the user for input in the form of
`raw_input('please provide foo')`.

I have a bash script which among other things executes that python script:

```
NUM_OUTPUT=$(python -i create_lookup_txtfiles.py data-dir=/data/ad6813/pipe-data/Bluebox/raw_data/dump to-dir=/data/ad6813/caffe/data_info/$TASK_NAME bad-min=$BAD_MIN)
```

I would like to run this bash script and provide input (as a user, via interactive shell) to the python script's prompts when need be.

But when I run the bash script, I do not see the python prompts.

I have also tried without the `-i` flag, to no avail.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: How are you running the python script in the shell script?

Comment: do you want user input or a scripted auto input?

Comment: How does the python script ask for input? Does it detect its running environment?

Comment: @EtanReisner python script asks for input with `raw_input('give me foo')`. I don't know how to determine whether it detects its running environment, could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to distinguish between the prompt string and the script output, so need to use a different file to write your prompt from Python. An example with tty is below, but you can also use stderr for prompts:

*bash script:*

```
m=$(python d.py)
echo "OUTPUT $m"
```

*python script:*

```
import os
tty=os.open("/dev/tty", os.O_RDWR)
os.write(tty, "Enter> ");
s=raw_input("")
print s
```

the same bash script should also work with stderr prompts:

*python script:*

```
import sys 
sys.stderr.write("Enter> ");
s=raw_input("")
print s
```

Comment: write all interactive messages to stderr from python. only put the thing you want to capture to stdout.

Comment: Why use "print s" then? Shouldn't he just print using stderr?

Comment: @Kasisnu, that's also true, if all prompts go to stdout and the capture goes to the stderr then from bash these handles can be swapped .